# Glassfish logs error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish

I am making a simple java ee app, deployed on a local glassfish server, in eclipse kepler. I have only one servlet called controller servlet. I thought everything was okay with my app until just checked the console window in eclipse and saw an exception for my glassfish server. I have a java file for the servlet  and the class file for this code must be somewhere because I clicked build project. So, why is it not able to find the class files ? The error does not give me any more useful information.

Please help me to figure out the reason for the error and fix it.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.controller.ControllerServlet
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:585)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)

    .........MUCH MORE....
```

Comment: Did you create a `ControllerServlet` inside a package called `java.controller`?

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza - Yes, I did. The java file is under My web project > Java resources > src > java.controller pakcage.

Comment: Assuming you have deployed the app as a WAR, what is its structure? Can you add this to the original post please?

Comment: You should not have any own package whose name starts with `java`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Wow. You are right. Why does this name cause a problem ? Thanks.

Comment: If anyone likes this question please give me +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have any own package whose name starts with `java`. Replace the name of `java.controller` package to something else like `myapp.controller` and do this for other packages in your project with the same pattern. After that, redeploy the application.

Exact explanation of problem identified above: [Java Language Specification. Chapter 6. Names. 6.1. Declarations.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)

> *Names of packages intended only for local use should have a first identifier that begins with a lowercase letter, but that first identifier specifically should not be the identifier `java;` package names that start with the identifier `java` are reserved for package of the Java SE platform.*

Comment: I'd been surprised if the name of the package is the problem here, although I agree you should not have your own packages starting with 'java'

Comment: yes, that works. Very strange. I wonder why this error occurs. Actually, I saw a sample project folder which had the folder java > controller. The servlet java
code was inside this. So, I assumed that I have to create a package named java.controller to replicate this structure. Is there any other way one can replicate
the structure, instead of creating packages. Thanks.

Comment: @james you probably got confused. Java is the generic name for the main source folder, usually for maven projects. Then, the package stars with controller.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza - So, I create a new `src` folder called java under the src folder called "src", and then make a `package` controller inside java ?

Comment: @james please read the post. It contains the solution to your problem.

Comment: Oh wait, I just created the same structure by creating a new `src` folder with name java/controller. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: @  Luiggi Mendoza - Yes, I tried that solution. But, I also wanted to replicate the example's folder structure and see if that works. Will update soon.

Comment: @james Given your original code, your class is called ControllerServlet which resides in a package called controller. Hence, its Full Qualified Name (FQN) is controller.ControllerServlet. The folder java is not part of the name. It is the root folder for you to add your classes to. It wasn't so much a renaming problem but more a misunderstanding of where the packages root folder is.

Comment: @JamesB added explanation about it. Yes, you **must not** have a package whose name starts with `java`, that's the reason of the problem.

Comment: @james added an explanation about the origin of your problem.